# Can not set decimal value as default in dropdownlistfor asp.net core using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

if value is not decimal then work fine but only problem with decimal value in below code

`$('select#listspec_0__qty option[value = 105.3]').attr("selected", true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Double Quotation "105.3"

```
 $('select#listspec_0__qty option[value = "105.3"]').attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

use quotation marks for value:

```
$('select#listspec_0__qty option[value = "105.3"]').attr("selected", true);
```